# Audio player in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a audio player feature to add to my app, I would like to have a play, stop/pause, and progessbar option for the player. I reffered to https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Example_WorkingWithAudio/. I want to implement the feature for android, iOS, and windows.

Are there any available plugins which I can use or any other reference link which can help..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Xamarin-Forms-Labs Plugin](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)  it has a Audioservice.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform/Services/Media/ISoundService.cs) for the interface.

And [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/SoundServiceViewModel.cs)  an usage example

Comment: Does this plugin have play, pause, fast forward and progress bar feature for playing audio?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same issue, you can achieve this by creating the audio player yourself with help of dependency service and native (platform specific) api's.